# How to check if a a range of strings in a column, are contained in another column in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check a range of strings using a macro

(example of strings: string sometimes contains numbers: VNVININT2HAI, BRKARLTD999FRA)

in a column (H3:H100) in Sheet1 and if it exists in a column(K2:K100) in Sheet2

then mark the cells in Sheet1 either green if the string matches up with any of the strings in the column in Sheet2. Then Mark the Cells in Sheet1 either green if it matches or red if it doesnt.

I've googled for answers found mostly code for integers, and formulas using Vlookup, not the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: you include some screenshots or post a sample file of what you're doing I'll add it into my answer. I suspect it isn't very hard.  You should also delete your answer as that isn't what SO considers a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple questions. However I'll answer part of it by saying **[COUNTIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function)** is an underrated tool for CHECKING if something exists or not. Countif is desirable because it can check cells without throwing errors as **VLookup** or **Match** might.

Example for checking if value exists in a range could be written like this in excel `=OR(COUNTIF(E:E,"VNVININT2HAI"))` which would return `True` if any cell had a value of your text.

You can also use it to check if a cell contains it by using * for the sides.

Example: `=OR(COUNTIF(E6,"*2*"))` would return `True` or `False` depending if a cell contains a "2" anywhere in it.

I doubt this fully answers your question, but for people looking on how to "check cells and ranges" **COUNTIF** is probably more useful than you think. It's applicable in VBA too (sometimes I prefer it over [instr).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

**EDIT**
This works, but if you have a LOT of cells to check, perhaps consider using `IsNumber(Match()` as shown in comments by @scottCraner

Comment: thank you, i will continue researching/googling COUNTIF for an answer .

Comment: I messed around on google sheets to see if I could do the same thing... you can see it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wv4jkZlC-u-zSDGI-3oClO2SX3XgtdpP3-qn1dvbiP8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: COuNTIF is a calc hog.  Fill column A with the row number out to 100,000 rows and then add the formula: `=OR(COUNTIF(A:A,A1))` and fill down the same number of rows.  Depending on your machine this may take a while.  `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,A:A,0))` is much quicker.

Comment: @ScottCraner you're so mean. You didn't tell me that if I performed your test my laptop would become inoperable for five minutes and start smoking....  

Umm... yeah `IsNumber(Match(A1,A:A,0)` might be better.... took about 2 seconds. So if you have a lot of calcs... do that instead!

Comment: @PGCodeRider I did say `Depending on your machine this may take a while.`  Sorry.

Comment: @ScottCraner I was being facetious, thanks for sharing, and no apology needed -- it was a great contribution. I was just trying to articulate how indeed correct you were by cracking a joke. I'm actually a comedian (and my success can be measured in the frequency in which I have to explain my jokes).

Comment: Wrong audience then, most likely my fault.  I tend to drift a little closer to Mr. Spock than Doctor McCoy.

Comment: @ScottCraner No worries. I didn't watch Star Wars much, but I get your point. Have a good night.

Comment: Okay, so far having it cross check the column from a different sheet was unsuccessful. I've added the column to the same sheet, and it gets the job done. But i would really like it to pull from a different sheet, or even better a different workbook, because the workbook gets continually updated.

Comment: @DannyNguyen, I just happened to see your reply now (two months later). If by chance you haven't figured it out, you would need to specify the sheet that contains the column you wish to check, WITHIN the formula. Without this, Excel will assume you mean the activesheet. So if it was Sheet1, the formula would need to read `=OR(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1))` if the sheet name has a space you would need single quotes around it such as `=OR(COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!A:A,A1))`.

Assuming that works (which it will), I'd appreciate you clicking the tick so I can try to pass @ScottCraner's score by the year 2230.