# Formula to display values in one column that do NOT appear in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to know which values in column A do NOT appear anywhere in column B. Right now I have conditional formatting to highlight those cells, but I'd love to have a listing of the values in another column so that I don't have to manually go through and pull the values myself.

[Sample sheet is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dHHnlNKz3xtgzyRXdKCNjoz4RNb9bcDSwZKhkbfYOXw/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this should do it. I put it in your sheet.

Update, sorry I misread first time.

`=FILTER(A2:A,ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A,$B:$B,FALSE)))`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(COUNTIFS(B2:B, A2:A)))
```

Comment: Nice. I don't use CountIFs. I got shown up that it was a memory hog in this post of mine. Read the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262008/how-to-check-if-a-a-range-of-strings-in-a-column-are-contained-in-another-colum/54262238#54262238