# How to avoid repeating multiple arguments to AND function for a contiguous range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, operators

I have this google sheets input.

| Players | Loot |
| --- | --- |
| Player1 | 4 |
| Player2 | 1 |
| Player3 | 4 |
| Player4 | 2 |

What I'm seeking to do is to **simplify** this formula.

```
=AND(B2>=3,B3>=3,B4>=3,B5>=3)
```

[image]

This is what i did so far. as suggested by [@Harun24hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74297721/timeline#comment_131170574).

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(B2:B5>=3,"TRUE"))=COUNTA(B2:B5)
```

Can this formula be simplified further and still get `TRUE` in a **single cell** when all of Loot values is `>=` 3?

Comment: @pgSystemTester I know it's not you I thing he is someone doesn't even answer's questions and not only my questions, the last month is increasing

Comment: I mean by simpler: shorter, straightforward less wasted steps, something may be or will to be a standard method, and maybe rewarded with a bounty. @pgSystemTester

Comment: The questions is updated @TheMaster take a look

Comment: @OSM Your title improves your question (to me), as it suggests that you're trying to get an AND evaluation across a dynamic range/array. This is indeed puzzling as intuitive `AND` array functions do not work. At the same time, your clarified title also provides evidence to critics who might consider your question a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets) from five years ago with a most similar title: *ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the entire range `B2:B5` and check if it's  greater than or equal to `3` using `>=`. `>=` operator supports arrays. `AND` merges the values.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(B2:B5>=3))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand exactly what you mean by *simpler*, but this formula is dynamic which I would consider simpler....?

```
=Count(filter(B2:B,B2:B>=3))=Count(B2:B)
```

Also, I try to avoid using `CountTf` after [@ScottCraner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) mercilessly taught me the in the comments sections of [one of my less impressive answers from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262238/11732320) by saying:

> *COuNTIF is a calc hog. Fill column A with the row number out to 100,000 rows and then add the formula: =OR(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)) and fill down the same number of rows. Depending on your machine this may take a while. =ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)) is much quicker.*

My computer pretty much melted (though that was an Excel Discussion while this is Google sheets?).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262238/19529694) thoroughly. @pgSystemTester

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B>=3)=COUNTA(B2:B)
```